# What does "$\;\lfloor y \rfloor\;$" mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could someone clarify the what the "L" and "inverted L" brackets on the $y$ variable mean? Is it weirdly formatted absolute value brackets or something different?

[image]

Comment: It is the floor function. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor $, then $f$ is the 'floor' function, and it can be expanded as:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & \textrm{if }x \in \mathbb{Z} \\ n, & \textrm{if $n$ is the biggest integer such that } n< x\end{cases}$$